# GoogleConntectionFactory can't create connection

Tags: spring, spring-social

G'day everybody!

I've got error like this:

```
WARN/DefaultRequestDirector(22739): Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of
these challenges: {authsub=WWW-Authenticate: AuthSub
realm="https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubRequest" allowed-
scopes="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email,
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile,
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.id"}
```

It's happend when I wanna get connection:

```
AccessGrant accessGrant = new AccessGrant(accessToken);
Connection<Google> connection = connectionFactory.createConnection(accessGrant);
```

As the result, I catch exception as Auth 401.

Did any one that problem befor?

Comment: I guess that is happend because of DefaultRequestDirector can't respond on scopes key at request...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found why it was happened. The problem was in scope. I set only https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me    scope. It wasn't enough for create connection.

As result, I had the next message:

```
WARN/DefaultRequestDirector(22739): Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of
these challenges: {authsub=WWW-Authenticate: AuthSub
realm="https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubRequest" allowed-
scopes="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email,
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile,
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.id"}
```

As you can see google oauth2 asks for https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.id scopes.

After I had added this scopes and I got a new error likes "invalid_scope".

Problem was in connection url.

I created connection url as:

```
connectionFactory.getOAuthOperations().buildAuthorizeUrl(GrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE, params);
```

where params:

```
OAuth2Parameters params = new OAuth2Parameters();
params.setRedirectUri(redirectUri);
params.setScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email+" + "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile+" + "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.id+" + 
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me");
```

In this case, symbol "+" was decoded to another one and Google oauth2 api couldn't recognize  scope set.

I hope this solution will help somebody in future.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the old AuthSub authentication when you should be using OAuth2 authentication. I suggest you take a look at the [example application](https://github.com/GabiAxel/spring-social-google/tree/master/spring-social-google-quickstart/spring-social-quickstart), specifically see in [SocialConfig](https://github.com/GabiAxel/spring-social-google/blob/master/spring-social-google-quickstart/spring-social-quickstart/src/main/java/org/springframework/social/quickstart/config/SocialConfig.java) how to create ProviderSignInController which is used for sign in.

Comment: I use OAuth2, but I can't create Connection<Google> =/

Comment: The log you included states an attempt to use AuthSub. Again I suggest you replicate the example application to get started.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't use social-spring in android app